# Changing a select drop-down list to an unordered list

Tags: html, css, select, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I created a drop-down menu with the select and option tags, however these do not allow me to link to my other web pages, I read that I had to create an un-ordered list because i create my drop-down incorrectly.

here's what my code currently looks like: 
https://jsfiddle.net/pferdefleisch/Q7HNj/1/

```
<select id="one">


<option value = "catalouge">
<a href = "catalouge.html">PRODUCT CATALOUGE</a>
</option>


<option>
    Vacuum Components
</option>

<option>
    Valve Components
</option>

<option>
    Roughing Components
</option>

<option>
    Vacuum Measurement
</option>

<option>
    Glass Components
</option>

<option>
    Electrical Feedthroughs
</option>

<option>
    Motion and manipulation
</option>

<option>
    Thin Film Products
</option>
</select>
```

css:

```
 #one { 
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px; 
  width: 20%;
  font-family: Palatino Linotype;
  font-size: 15px;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px purple inset;
  list-style: none;

  position:absolute;top:23%;left:2%;
}
```

How would I transform this into a normal drop-down list?

Comment: Use bootstrap my friend, use bootstrap :: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: This looks pretty normal to me already. What do you mean that it doesn't allow you to link to other pages?

Comment: I'm using this as my navigation bar, I want to link to other .html pages but I heard this was the incorrect way of doing things

Comment: Please post your javascript code (instead of linking it) so that others may find it when they search for a similar problem.

Comment: I don't have any Javascript code relating to this and my problem is not solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using a selection drop-down. Here is a fiddle I made of how you would probably want to do it. This fiddle is purely HTML and CSS.

https://jsfiddle.net/2q3kkh8n/2/

The HTML

```
<div id="dropdown-container">
    <div id="dropdown">PRODUCT CATALOGUE
        <span class="down-arrow-icon">><span>
    </div>
    <ul id="dropdown-list">
        <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#dropdown-container{
    float: left;
    font-family: Palatino Linotype;
}
#dropdown{
    padding:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(169, 169, 169);
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #2961c1 inset;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px purple inset;
}
.down-arrow-icon{    
    padding-left: 5px;
    /*place img of down arrow here*/
}
#dropdown-list{
    display:none;
    width: 100%; 
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(169,169,169);
}
#dropdown-container:hover ul#dropdown-list{
    display:block;
}
#dropdown-container ul{
    padding:0px;
    list-style: none;
}
#dropdown-container ul li{
    width: 100%;
}
#dropdown-container ul li:hover{
    background-color: lightblue;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#dropdown-container ul li a{  
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: black;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped. how would I go about styling the drop-down like I had it?

Comment: I updated the fiddle, HTML and CSS to reflect the style you're looking for. One behavior that you will not be able to accomplish with just HTML and CSS is the click event to open and close the menu. If you wish to do this, the best route would be to use a little bit of JavaScript. If hover to open works for you, then there is no need for the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your pages with select also.
Just include jquery library and put this jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#one').change(function(){
         window.location.href = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    });
});
```

If you want to use the select for a main menu it is better to use unordered list:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="link to page 1">Page 1 Title</a></li>
        <li><a href="link to page 2">Page 2 Title</a></li>
        <li><a href="link to page 3">Page 3 Title</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I heard that using select was pretty amateur and incorrect though?

Comment: I changed my answer you will choose which of the two variants to use.